# Python - Reply to email win32com

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I am trying to reply to an email via python and win32com. 
Below is my code :

```
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items


    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == "aaa":
            print("Found message")             
            message.body="This is a reply"        
            message.Reply()
```

The reply is getting sent to the sender of "aaa" but the previous email on which I am trying to reply does not appear below the new email.The history of emails on which I am replying gets lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the means to test this, but from the code you shared, I think the problem is as follows:

you iterate over `messages` and each found **MailItem** is assigned the loop variable "message".
Next you set the `body` of `message` as "*This is a reply*" - in other words: **You overwrite the original message** with the new string and then send the reply.
`.Reply()` then simply creates a new MailItem object from `message`, just with `Sender` and `Recipient` Properties switched... and the new `body` you yourself assigned it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)

EDIT:

So I made this code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
acc = outlook.Folders("myemail@provider.com")
inbox = acc.folders("Inbox")   #change to localized versions
drafts = acc.folders("Drafts") #if necessary

def createReply(email:object):
        reply = email.Reply()
        newBody = "Dear friend,\n\nThis should be added on top.\nI hope this 
                   works\n\nkr\ntst\n"
        reply.HTMLBody = newBody + reply.HTMLBody
        reply.Move(drafts)

for mailItem in inbox.Items:
        if mailItem.Subject == "Test4Reply":
                print("Start")
                createReply(mailItem)
```

First, I sent an email to myself with the Subject line "Test4Reply" so I can grab that. I added some gibberish into the Email body, just to check if it gets retained. Then, I created a new MailItem Object `reply` from the email in my inbox using the `.Reply()` Method, which I then moved (with `.Move()`) into my Drafts folder. There I can inspect it and see that, indeed, the original email is preserved in the history, as well as the Subject line automatically gaining the "AW: " prefix.

So:
To preserve the original email, you just need to make sure to not overwrite the original `Body` and only insert new text at the beginning of the `MailItem.HTMLBody`.

Comment: You are right. I tried creating new email object but do not see any means for reply to an email keeping previous conversations intact. Reply()/ReplyAll() do not take new email object I created as argument.Not sure if win32com can suffice my requirement.

Comment: I will be at my workstation in a bit, I can try it out and do some tests then. `Reply()` should not send the email yet though, right? According to the docs, it only creates a new MailItem object which you then have to send by calling `.Send`

Comment: Already appreciating your help. I tried for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == "aaa":         
              
       
        newMessage=message.Reply()
        newMessage.body="Body in reply"
        newMessage.Send() but it did the same as in original question :(

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I updated the answer with my code.

Comment: You can concat the existing body with a new body, unfortunately that destroys all the formatting. I have not been able to get Python to read the `MailItem.Body` as HTML, it only seems to support plain text.
So while the reply itself has the proper formatting, once you add to the string, it turns everything into plain text.

Comment: Hey! Thanks it worked. It at least retained the previous mail. A little better formatting after I concatenated my MailItem.HTMLBody.Will still have to do the manipulation in the mail body to make it look like its actually an email chain.Appreciate your help..Cheers!

Comment: Oh... yeah I just figured it out. The HTMLBody is literally all you need. I added to my code in the above answer! Obviously the linebreaks in my `newBody`string dont show, because it now should be HTML formatted, not plain text.